# QML GridView hide one cell

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

It's possible to hide certain cell in GridView? I set delegate, but I still got empty place for this GridView element. It's possible to do this?

```
visible: false
width: 0
height: 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by hiding, for example if the delegate is a rectangle and it is in the middle you want that space to be empty, or do not leave any space.

Comment: Second case, I want hide one cell in a grid and reorder other cells to not leave free space.

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: It looks lke you're talking about [Layout.rowSpan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#rowSpan-attached-prop)

Comment: I think the only way is to eliminate the item from the model.

Comment: I got Qt model based on QAbstracModel. @eyllanesc I was afraid that it's a only way.

Comment: @MichałKluska Use a QSortFilterProxyModel to hide, if you show how you created your model, you could show a solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc QSortFilterProxyModel is one of solution. Other one is change GridView on Grid with Repeater inside and all in Flickable. It look the same, work the same and I can hide certain item using visible, height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was said in the comment, you can indeed use a QSortFilterProxy model, but here is another solution. You could implement a pure-QML FilterProxyModel, using `DelegateModel` and `DelegateModelGroup`

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQml.Models 2.3

DelegateModel {

    property var filterAccepts: function(item) {
        return true
    }

    onFilterAcceptsChanged: refilter()

    function refilter() {
        if(hidden.count>0)
            hidden.setGroups(0, hidden.count, "default")
        if(items.count>0)
            items.setGroups(0, items.count, "default")
    }

    function filter() {
        while (unsortedItems.count > 0) {
            var item = unsortedItems.get(0)
            if(filterAccepts(item.model))
                item.groups = "items"
            else
                item.groups = "hidden"
        }
    }

    items.includeByDefault: false
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: default
            name: "default"
            includeByDefault: true
            onChanged: filter()
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: hidden
            name: "hidden"
        }
    ]

}
```

**Explanation**: Every time an item is added to the model, it is added in the "default" group, which triggers the `onChanged` handler that will call `filter()`.

Filter() will look for items in the default group, and move them either in the `items` group (which will make them visible) or to the `hidden` group, depending on the result of the filterAccepts function.

When filterAccept changes, the SortProxyModel will move every item to the default group to trigger a global refiltering.

You can then use your proxy model like this:

```
FilterProxyModel
{
    id: filterProxyModel

    model: <YourBaseModel>
    delegate: <YourDelegate>

    filterAccepts: function(item) {
          // Eg: Only "small" items will be displayed
          return item.size == "small"
    }
}

GridView
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: filterProxyModel
    cellHeight: 100
    cellWidth: 100
}
```

Comment: `unsortedItems` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified solution with QML only, based on hiding items.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    id: window
    title: "test"
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    GridLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 4
        Repeater {
            id: container
            model: 20
            Rectangle {
                id: item
                property int itemIndex: index
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                height: 60
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text:item.itemIndex
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        item.visible = false;
                        layout.doIt(item.itemIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function doIt(index)
        {
            var item = container.itemAt(index);
            if(item)
                item.visible = false;
            for(var i = index - 1;i >= 0;i --)
            {
                var prev_item = container.itemAt(i);
                if(prev_item.visible) {
                    prev_item.Layout.columnSpan ++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The given code won't work on GridViews.